# Testing for equality of variance for more than 2 groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, multiple-comparisons, permutation-test, f-test

How do you test for equality of variance between, say, 3 groups? Is there an extension of the two-sample F-test? Or is it OK to just run multiple F-tests or permutation tests among 3 groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's several possible tests, including [Bartlett's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartlett%27s_test) and [Hartley's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartley%27s_test), but both are pretty sensitive to the normality assumption; some people choose to use less sensitive alternatives like Levene's test or the Brown-Forsythe test. However, if you're doing this in order to decide whether to assume equal variance in (say) one-way ANOVA, you're generally better not to assume it (though if the sample sizes are equal, ANOVA isn't very sensitive to unequal variances in any case).

Comment: The most straightforward generalization to $k > 2$ samples of the F-ratio test for two variances is Bartlett's test, which also assumes normal data. To add to the list of links: [Levene's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levene%27s_test) is a predecessor to and special case of the Brown-Forsythe test.